# Looking for a good hash table implementation in C

Tags: c, string, hashtable, hash

I am primarily interested in string keys. Can someone point me towards a library?

Answer (score 61):

I had the same need and did some research and ended up using [libcfu](http://freecode.com/projects/libcfu)

It's simple and readable so if I have a need to modify, I can do it without spending too much time to understand. It's also of BSD license. No need to change my structs (to embed say a next pointer)

I had to reject the other options for following reasons (my personal reasons, YMMV):

- sglib --> it's a macro maze and I wasn't comfortable debugging/making
  changes on such a code base using just macros
- cbfalconer --> lot of licensing redflags, and the site was down and too many unfavorable discussions on web about support/author; didn't want to take the risk
- google sparce-hash --> as stated already, it's for C++, not C
- glib (gnome hash) --> looked very promising; but I couldn't find any easy way to install the developer kit; I just needed the C routines/files -- not the full blown developement environment
- Judy --> seems too complex for a simple use.. also was not ready to debug myself if I had to run into any issues
- npsml (mentioned here) --> can't find the source
- [strmap](http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html) found very simple and useful -- it's just too simplistic that both key and value must be strings; value being string seems too restrictive (should accept void *)
- [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) --> seems good (has been mentioned on wikipedia on hashtable); found that it requires struct to be modified -- didn't want to do that as performace is not really a concern for my use --it's more of development velocity.

In summary for very simple use strmap is good; uthash if you are concerned with additional memory use. If just speed of development or ease of use is primary objective, libcfu wins [note libcfu internally does memory allocation to maintain the nodes/hashtables]. It's surprising that there aren't many simple C hash implementations available.

Comment: i notice uthash seems to be more actively developed than libcfu (2005 vintage). perhaps this isn't an issue for a small bit of code though - have you come across any other contenders since this post?

Comment: I have a huge dataset, and glib does not support that big data (32-bit keys). I need more than glib. How about libcfu?

Comment: libcfu link is showing an error...

Comment: The hashtable implementation in CPython is based on libcfu: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/hashtable.c

Comment: Libcfu 's document: http://libcfu.sourceforge.net/libcfu.html

Comment: Finally I choose UTHash on Android. Some notes: if occured `fall-through between switch labels`, please use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-fallthrough"`; 
if occured `padding struct 'struct UT_hash_table' with 4 bytes to align 'tail'`, see https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash/issues/118#issue-223582662

Answer (score 16):

GLib is a great library to use as a foundation in your C projects. They have some decent data structure offerings including Hash Tables: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html (link updated 4/6/2011)

Comment: +1: Glib is indeed a great library.

Comment: am i right in thinking you usually dynamically link to the glib library to use these data structures, potentially creating porting issues if moving from linux to windows?

Comment: Glib supports only 32-bit. If you work with huge data, glib won't be a good choice

Answer (score 8):

For strings, the [Judy Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array) might be good.

> A Judy array is a complex but very fast associative array data structure for storing and looking up values using integer or string keys. Unlike normal arrays, Judy arrays may be sparse; that is, they may have large ranges of unassigned indices.

Here is a [**Judy library** in **C**](http://judy.sourceforge.net/).

> A C library that provides a state-of-the-art core technology that implements a sparse dynamic array. Judy arrays are declared simply with a null pointer. A Judy array consumes memory only when it is populated, yet can grow to take advantage of all available memory if desired.

---

Other references,
This [Wikipedia hash implementation reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Implementations) has some **`C`** open source links.
Also, [**cmph**](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) -- A Minimal Perfect Hashing Library in `C`, supports several algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

There are some good answers here:
[[Container Class / Library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c/306461#306461)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c/306461#306461)

http://sglib.sourceforge.net.

http://cbfalconer.home.att.net/download/

Answer (score 5):

Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/)  includes a fine hash table and several other well-engineered data structures.  There is also a nice string-processing interface.  The book is great if you can afford it, but even if not, I have found this software very well designed, small enough to learn in its entirety, and easy to reuse in several different projects.

Comment: Dang! I need to buy this!

Answer (score 5):

A long time has passed since I asked this question...  I can now add my own public domain library to the list:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npsml/

Answer (score 4):

[C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/) discusses hash table implementations in C. The source code is [available online](http://code.google.com/p/cii/source/browse/#svn/tags/v20). (My copy of the book is at work so I can't be more specific.)

Comment: Thanks for introducing this book. Just placed an order in Amazon.

Answer (score 3):

Apache's APR library has its own [hash-implementation](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__hash.html). It is already ported to anything Apache runs on and the [Apache license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) is rather liberal too.

Comment: This looks to be a really practical choice for C programming. It has everything, widely used and tested, well documented, ..

Answer (score 3):

khash.h from samtools/bwa/seqtk/klib

curl https://raw.github.com/attractivechaos/klib/master/khash.h

via http://www.biostars.org/p/10353/

Comment: although khash looks like it's written to be very efficient, one thing it lacks is documentation/an toy example of it in use...

Comment: there are examples here http://www.biostars.org/p/10353/

Comment: I see one example, which doesn't offer any explanation and similar to the docs it has one letter non-descriptive variable names and no comments. It's annoying as no doubt it's doing something straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Never used it but [Google Sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) may work

Comment: I thought that sparsehase written in C++.

Comment: Indeed, C is the language of interest in this case--not C++.

Answer (score 2):

Download [tcl](http://www.activestate.com) and use their time-proven tcl hash function. It's easy. The TCL API is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dozylynx/C-hashtable

[updated URL as original now 404s: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~cwc22/hashtable/ ]

Defined functions

```
* create_hashtable
* hashtable_insert
* hashtable_search
* hashtable_remove
* hashtable_count
* hashtable_destroy
```

Example of use

```
  struct hashtable  *h;
  struct some_key   *k;
  struct some_value *v;

  static unsigned int         hash_from_key_fn( void *k );
  static int                  keys_equal_fn ( void *key1, void *key2 );

  h = create_hashtable(16, hash_from_key_fn, keys_equal_fn);

  insert_key   = (struct some_key *) malloc(sizeof(struct some_key));
  retrieve_key = (struct some_key *) malloc(sizeof(struct some_key));

  v = (struct some_value *) malloc(sizeof(struct some_value));

  (You should initialise insert_key, retrieve_key and v here)

  if (! hashtable_insert(h,insert_key,v) )
  {     exit(-1);               }

  if (NULL == (found = hashtable_search(h,retrieve_key) ))
  {    printf("not found!");                  }

  if (NULL == (found = hashtable_remove(h,retrieve_key) ))
  {    printf("Not found\n");                 }

  hashtable_destroy(h,1); /* second arg indicates "free(value)" */
```

Comment: 404 error. Would you update the link, please?

Comment: I am the author of the above hash table. The code is available at:
https://github.com/dozylynx/C-hashtable

Answer (score 0):

Gperf - Perfect Hash Function Generator

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gperf.html

Answer (score -1):

stl has map and hash_map (hash_map is only in some implementations) that are key to value if you are able to use C++.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/