# Plain C implementation of a mapping from single char to pointer

Tags: c, dictionary, implementation

I have programming experience with higher-level languages, and have started coding in plain C a couple of weeks ago (for academic reasons). I want to implement a data structure something like a `map<char,myStruct*>`.

If that isn't clear enough: I want a "mapping" for every possible SINGLE `char` onto a pointer to a structure I define somewhere else. If there was a way to ensure that no 2 `char`s can point to the same `struct` (without checking every other `char` when inserting a new element onto the map) that would be neat, but that is not strictly necessary. I also need to be able to remove pairings from the map, and to reinsert the pairings with the same Key but different pointers.

I have thought this through, and figured I could create a pointer array the length of all possible chars, and just store the corresponding pointer using the char as the array index (since it is just a number constant). This might very well work but it seems kind of inefficient to allocate that much space for addresses if I end up using only a couple of chars in my application.

Still, I wasn't able to think of any alternative solutions (considering I'm a C newbie, not that surprising). I would be grateful for any, if even vague, suggestions in the right direction.

Comment: I suggest you look into the Glib library -- it includes hashes and all sorts of things. You can "steal" some ideas from them.

If you want "templates" it's going to get ugly, if you want to implement a map for just your strict types, it's not that difficult. The general idea behind pure C "templates" or "generics" is to tell your container the "sizeof" of the struct and use that. Then use #define'd macros to cast stuff to specific types when accessing it. The actual struct memory is then stored as a char array.

Comment: The basic idea is to use functions that operate on a struct.  The struct will need to know certain things about the map it represents: size of the keys, size of the stored data, pointer to a hashing function (if you want it to be configurable), so on.  I remember seeing a few youtube videos from Standford semi related to this, and will see if I can find them.

Comment: What you want is called a hash table. And my guess is that your key is a string, so that would be a char*, not a char (that could be implemented by a plain `void * array[256];` ).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @wildplasser My key is not a string, but a **single** char. I wasn't being clear enough and edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: An array is the most efficient solution. If you cannot afford 128 (or 256) pointers, you are **really* tight on memory. If the payload has a fixed size per item, you could even create an array of payload. That would have *zero* overhead cost, since you'll have to store the payload anyway.

Comment: Yes, but my payload is dynamically allocated, so it would mean quite more overhead than storing the 256 pointers. You are probably right, the space for the pointers should be there.

Comment: Also, could someone please tell me  what I am supposed to append to the question to mark it as answered, or is it sufficient if I accept an answer?

Comment: If the payload is fixed size there is no need for dynamic allocation. (malloc has overhead too, and rounds up to some 2**n size). Preallocation is the way to go, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you say (and as a commenter suggested), the easiest thing is to just do an array with a static size equal to the max value of the character data type:

```
#include <limits.h>
void * mapping[1u << CHAR_BIT];
```

Assuming 64-bit pointers and 8-bit `char`s, this would occupy 8 * 256 = 2,048 bytes of memory for the entire map (excluding of course the "user data" which is what you store). For a program running on a 64-bit system, 2 KB of memory is trivial, and the ease of implementation and speed you get from this should balance the wasted memory quite nicely, in my opinion.

The simplest thing to do if you still want to limit the "physical" size of the array would be to hash the single character, but then you need to start dealing with hash collision which immediately makes it more complicated.

You could do something like:

```
struct ValueChain
{
  struct ValueChain *next;
  void *value;
  char key;
}

#define MAP_SIZE 127 /* This should be prime. */
struct ValueChain* mapping[MAP_SIZE];
```

Here we've halved the size of the pointer array, but the cost of each value has increased. Also you're going to need dynamic allocations when inserting collided values.

You could further compact it by doing e.g.

```
#define MAP_SIZE 31
struct ValueChain mapping[MAP_SIZE];
```

Here each value in the array is a full `ValueChain` "list header", rather than just a pointer to one. On a 64-bit machine this would probably use about 558 bytes for the `mapping` array, but you wouldn't need to do any dynamic allocations until you detect a collision.

The hashing for these could be just `const char key = myChar % MAP_SIZE;` to a first approximation, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your key is a string.

Well... If you are not required to implement this on your own just **[don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c)**.

> In theory it's not that hard.

Create an array that contain keys and values and an optional pointer to a linked list.

On accessing the hash map take the modulo of the hashed key, this is the position in your array. Then you have to compare the unhashed key with the stored key to detect collisions. If they match you found it. If not, you have to loop through the linked list and compare the keys until they match.

Obviously this is a trivial implementation and you can do much more to save memory and improve performance.

Comment: My key is NOT a string. It is a single char, and I don't need to hash for something that simple (I edited the title to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct myStruct array[1u << CHAR_BIT];

#define uchar_to_mystruct_ptr(c) (c >=0 && c < (1u << CHAR_BIT) ? &array[c] : NULL)
```

Comment: But this means reserving the space for every stuct there might be, even if they are quite big. I am working for an embedded system and thus want to only use memory for (char, pointer) pairings that are actually inserted into the mapping.

Comment: So you have *very few* entries (say 10..20) ? Just use linear search (or binary search), using a table with {name,value} pairs.

Comment: I might have as few as 10 entries, but also a couple tens of thousands. I just need to keep the memory as clean as possible and avoid unused space.

Comment: A few thousand? How many characters do you have? BTW: "memory as clean as possible" := fixed allocation. Do you have an upper limit? If not: how do you know that your program will function once memory gets tight?

Comment: The character key is just a simplification right now. When developing anything, I always try to plan ahead and keep everything as scalable and as changeable with minimal cost involved (even if I know for sure it won't be changed or scaled, but to train the habit of good software engineering).
Still, this is not a 'real' application but an excercise I'm doing for learning, so debating about it has no real sense, since there aren't any real expectations regarding the system.
I thank you for your feedback since it did get me thinking about many flaws in my ideas.