# Stock information data structure for c?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm new to C(less than a week), and am trying to figure out a more effective way of retrieving data.  Basically imagine I have a few pieces of stock data: Ticker, price, change.

My approach so far has been to put all the data in 3 arrays. If I want the price of IBM, I search the ticker array and get the index location then get that location from the price array. It works fine but because I do a lot of lookups and my data doesn't change so I was wondering if there was maybe a more effective way of doing this?

I tried to look for a dictionary/hashmap to maybe store IBM as a key and a array of price/change as values, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in C.  If its possible is there a simple way to do this? I am working on a different program and really don't want to learn how to create my own from scratch(although if I have to, I def. will work on it).

Comment: You could use a `struct` to group the related pieces of information. Surely there is some public-domain hashtable code you can use for the lookup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c

Comment: You really should just switch to C++. Then you have things like list, map, unordered_map, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://uthash.sourceforge.net/

The examples on front page are pretty much self explanatory.

```
struct Stock {
   float price, change;
   char name[3];
   UT_hash_handle hh;
};

struct Stock * stocksHash = NULL;    
struct Stock * stockItem;
HASH_ADD_STR(stocksHash, name, stockItem );
HASH_FIND_STR(stocksHash, "IBM", stockItem );

//edit
void new_stock(struct Stock * stocksHash, char *name, float price, float change) {
    struct Stock *s;

    s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stock));
    strncpy (s->name, name, 3);
    s->price = price; s->change = change;
    s->id = user_id;
    HASH_ADD_STR( stocksHash, name, s );  
}

void update_stock (struct Stock * stocksHash, char *name, 
                   float price, float change) {
    struct Stock *s;
    HASH_FIND_STR (stocksHash, name, s);
    if (s) {
        s->price = price; s->change = change;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm still learning, do I need to malloc every time I add a new entry or if I want to add ibm and a price/change, will hash_add_str do it all for me? Are the above commands are there is?

Comment: @Error_404 I added some more examples. Yes - you have to `malloc` the memory when you add an item to the hash, and `free` when you're finished.