# State Machine of different Variables in C

Tags: c, if-statement, hashmap, lookup, state-machine

I have the following code which is doing lot of if-else check and consuming lot of time.

```
 while(i<1000) {

                if ( a == x1)
               {
                     if(b == y1)
                    {
                       array[i] = z1;
                    }
                    else if( b = y2)
                    {
                       array[i] = z2;
                    }
                    else if (b = z3);
                    {
                         array[i] = z3;
                    }
                    -
                    -
                    -
                    -
                    -
                   some 20 else --

                  }/*end of first if*/
                 else if (a == xx1)
                 {

                           if(b == yy1)
                          {
                               array[i] = zz1;
                          }
                          else (b == yyy3)
                         {
                              array[i] = zz2;
                         }
                         else ( b == yy4)
                        {
                           array[i] = zz3;
                        }
                          -
                          -
                          -
                          -
              -
             some 20 else --
        }
        else if(/*more conditions*/)
        {
            /* same as above with too many else loops */
        }
        -
        -
        -
        -
        -
        -
        -some 100 else-ifs
        -
        -
        -
        -
        -
        i++;
 }/*end of while*/
```

How can i minimize the time consumption.I though of a replacing if else with switch(switch within the switch) , but still i think i can do better with 
some tables(2d-3d array) but the numbers x1,y1,z1 ,zz3,zz1,zz2 are not continous numbers and have no relation among them they exists between 1 to 1 billion with no 
repetetion.Any thoughts for implementing this lookup table.
Rgds,
softy

Comment: Does that even compile? That aside, have you measured and actually identified a performance problem?

Comment: I hope this is demo code, because   if ( a = x1)
               {
                     if(b = y1) is going to fail as its using = not ==

Comment: What on earth *is* this code?

Comment: basically, the way you have presented the problem, without extra info, the "spec" is saying,  before I can do the 20th assignment I *MUST* check these 20 other conditions first.   You can't optimise that away unless you know something else that allows you to skip those checks

Comment: O..M..G! may god have mercy to anyone maintaining such a thing ...

Comment: @samy.vilar such thing is going good for ages, all i need is its rapidness, care 2 answer and not to critic !

Comment: @softy sorry, it may be `going good` but its still quite difficult to maintain, either-way I have a couple questions, are the underlying data types ints and how much memory do you have?

Answer (score 0):

(1) If the numbers are constants change it to case statement - your compiler should output a jump table if it can (given your constraints it can't - so go to step 2).

(2) If your data is non-contiguous a jump table won't work. You can make your data contiguous (or close enough to it) by using a hash table. Now just search the hash table. This should be O(1) (or close to it). Though you'll have to bear the cost of creating the hash table

If you need code for a hash table you can use C++ STL or if you need C write your own or find an implementation on the web, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c) might help.

Comment: you can't use a switch, the comparisons arent against a constant

Comment: also hash tables aren't going to be faster than the if elses

Comment: I don't see any where that there's any assignment to the numbers so I thought they were constant. Even if they aren't the hash table will work and will be faster if they are constant with in the loop (there will be an overhead of building the hash table though).

Comment: ok, hash would work if all the values are constant each iteration, and you add the values in least importance first ( so if there is a clash the one with the most significant value will be used).  you may want to edit your answer so it doesn't have the stuff about a switch

Comment: @KeithNicholas yes all assignments are constant, with all having equal probablity to occur !