# Writing a program to create variables as it needs them in C

Tags: c, variables, bioinformatics

I am writing a program in C to read in text from a FASTA file and for every name (ex. >COTV-SPAn232-096) I want my program to recognize the '>' and then use the following text before the \n to be used as the name for the variable.

The problem with hard coding the variables is that this program needs to be as dynamic as possible as it may be reading in an arbitrary number of different data sets. For example my testing set has 15 different sequences that look something like this:

> COTV-SPAn232-096
>   MKILNSYNDFIISFINFILFPTIQNVSISKLNILGYILSFIRIISISMDFDILKFSNIIQDYGLIFPDDIKKIQNEKFLVLERGLSGKLYAIHIYDFMARFDNETIFGIAKFLYRNNTKILDVLFINKDLFDKTDILYPKSTITLSSYSDEYIDYTYKTIKLIFLNLFNSFRFSKIDSKLSYLYLPLRKDINNVIL

The plan is read in the name of the sequence, set that name as the variable for a dynamic array and use malloc/realloc to handle storing the actual sequence for a later comparison of all the different sequences. I can handle everything except the variable variable names.

Briefly looking around for an answer to this, it seems as though it cannot be done in C though can be in python and some other languages. I am really hoping that is not the actual case though in the event that it is Does anyone have alternative suggestions for handling this problem? And yes this is bioinformatics and I probably should be using python, perl, java, or some other language but I would rather continue with this problem in C to become further versed in C.

Thanks in advance for any answers that I may receive!

Comment: Working in C as a way to become versed in C is understandable.  But given your field, how long are you going to stay in C?  More "modern" languages have text/string manipulation facilities that are so much better and easier to use than those of C, it's hard to imagine you staying in C in the long run.  However, learning C for a while is a worthy thing.

Comment: I recommend learning C, because Python is very slow at I/O operations. IME, on a modern Linux system, Python can be about 9-10x slower than C at reading from standard input and writing to standard output, even using "Pythonic" code. Much of bioinformatics is about parsing and processing text files, so if you plan to write software that operates as quickly as possible, C is not the only way to go, but it often performs much, much better than Python, Perl or other interpreted scripting languages.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible in C, but there is never a reason for creating variables with dynamic names (indeed, even once you created such variables in C, how would you use them?)

Instead, use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)- that's a data structure that maps from keys to values. In your case, you would want it to map from strings (your sequence names) to strings (your sequences).

Examples of C libraries for hash tables abound online: this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c) provides a few.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that it cannot be done in C, because C variables are a compile-time concept. Variables serve as "labels" for memory regions containing the data; once the compiler is done, the names of most variables are thrown away. They may be written to a separate file for the debugger, but that's a convenience for humans.

The good news is that you do not need a new variable to be named a new name. All you need is a second variable containing a name. A pair of variables - one for the `name` and one for the `value` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

> The plan is read in the name of the sequence, set that name as the variable for a dynamic array and use malloc/realloc to handle storing the actual sequence for a later comparison of all the different sequences. I can handle everything except the variable variable names.

Instead of naming the variable with the sequence header/name, create a `struct` that holds the sequence header/name and the sequence, e.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    char *header;
    char *sequence;
} fasta_t;
```

Then create a list of `fasta_t` pointers ("pointer to pointers"):

```
fasta_t **fasta_elements = NULL;
```

Use `malloc()` to allocate space for `N` elements of type `fasta_t *`, *e.g.*:

```
fasta_elements = malloc(N * sizeof(fasta_t *));
```

It's a good idea to check if you actually got the memory you asked for:

```
if (!fasta_elements) {
    /* i.e., if fasta_elements is still NULL */
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not allocate space for FASTA element list!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

(You should get into the habit of doing this with every pointer you `malloc()`, in my opinion.)

Now that space has been allocated, read in `N` elements (use `realloc()` if we need to make the list bigger, but let's assume `N` elements for now). Within a loop, allocate space for an individual `fasta_t` pointer, as well as space for header and sequence `char *`s within the `fasta_t` pointer:

```
#define MAX_HEADER_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH 4096

/* ... */

size_t idx;
char current_header[MAX_HEADER_LENGTH] = {0};
char current_sequence[MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH] = {0};

for (idx = 0U; idx < N; idx++) 
{
    /* set up space for the fasta_t struct members (the header and sequence pointers) */
    fasta_elements[idx] = malloc(sizeof(fasta_t));

    /* parse current_header and current_sequence out of FASTA input */
    /* ... */

    /* validate input -- does current_header start with a '>' character, for instance? */
    /* data in bioinformatics is messy -- validate input where you can */

    /* set up space for the header and sequence pointers */
    /* sizeof(char) is redundant in C, because sizeof(char) is always 1, but I'm putting it here for completeness */
    fasta_elements[idx]->header = malloc((strlen(current_header) + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
    fasta_elements[idx]->sequence = malloc((strlen(current_sequence) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    /* copy each string to the list pointer, for which we just allocated space */
    strncpy(fasta_elements[idx]->header, current_header, strlen(current_header) + 1);
    strncpy(fasta_elements[idx]->sequence, current_sequence, strlen(current_sequence) + 1);
}
```

To print out the `i+1`'th element's header, for example:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", fasta_elements[i]->header);
```

(Remember that indexing is 0-based in C — the 10th element has index 9, for instance.)

When finished, be sure to `free()` individual pointers within a `fasta_t *` pointer, the `fasta_t *` pointer itself, and then the `fasta_t **` pointer to pointers:

```
for (idx = 0U; idx < N; idx++) 
{
    free(fasta_elements[i]->header), fasta_elements[i]->header = NULL;
    free(fasta_elements[i]->sequence), fasta_elements[i]->sequence = NULL;
    free(fasta_elements[i]), fasta_elements[i] = NULL;
}
free(fasta_elements), fasta_elements = NULL;
```

For convenience, once you get the hang of dealing with `struct`s and memory management, you'll want to write wrapper functions that set up, access, edit and break down a `fasta_t *` element, as well as wrapper functions that do the same for a list of `fasta_t *` elements.