# dynamic hashset in C

Tags: c, hash, set

i need some kind of HashSet in C which can dynamicly grow in size. I could of course write everything on my own but maybe there is a good lib for that?
My Keys are 32bit hashes and i need to save a pointer (`struct dirent *`) as value.

Comment: Do you want the number of "buckets" to be dynamic, or that the number of entries in the hash-table be dynamic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c

Comment: @JoachimPileborg number of buckets.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend (as always) the nice [GLib (part of GTK+)](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/). It has the [`GHashTable`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) API which implements a hash table. It grows dynamically as needed.

To use 32-bit keys, reference the `g_int_hash()` and `g_int_equal()` functions when creating your hash table.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: DO NOT USE THIS LIBRARY FOR STRINGS!
See this ticket for more info: https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c/issues/4

The HashSet code from Couchbase seems nice:

https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c

Example:

```
#include "hashset.h"

char *foo = "foo";
char *missing = "missing";
hashset_t set = hashset_create();

if (set == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create hashset instance\n");
    abort();
}

hashset_add(set, foo);
assert(hashset_is_member(set, foo) == 1);
assert(hashset_is_member(set, missing) == 0);
```

Comment: I take it back, the library seems not well suited for string handling: It hashes based on the pointer address in memory...

Comment: Upped for the due diligence - I'd hate to choose that hashset and discover too late what you just did :)

Comment: @JohannGerell  Thanks mate :-) Yeah it bit me in the butt yesterday... :-( I even think it is ill suited for anything... It hashes based on the memory address... How is that useful for anything a bit more complex ? I can't believe it is used in couchbase...

Answer (score 1):

I successfully use this one: [KoanLogic Libu - Hmap module](http://www.koanlogic.com/libu/api/html/group__hmap.html)

The example in the link is enough self explaining. 
For your needs i guess you should use `U_HMAP_OPTS_DATATYPE_OPAQUE` as datatype and set the length of your key to 4 bytes with `u_hmap_opts_set_val_sz()`.

Comment: but the libu hmap does not support native uint32_t keys? i means its no big deal because of th QPAQUE feature...

Comment: The only difference is that you have to pass, as `hash key`, a `uint32_t` by pointer instead of `uint32_t` by value to the hash function