# Efficiently Finding if an element exists in a linked List

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Presuppose there is a linked list with information.   My Program architecture rests upon being able to find out if certain information already exists in an individual node in this linked list.

(Ie, see if the child integer value `int example` already has a value of 5 in some node.)

After that, each node can be systematically operated on.

I can think of various ways to do this, but I was hoping someone more experienced might show something fairly efficient.

Also, is this good practice, or should there be another, more suitable data structure out there?

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. Maybe some details on what you're doing with a linked list and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `O(N)` is not enough, sorted array and binary search, or a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) would give you `O(log(N))`. Alternatively you can look at [hashmap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). This structure will give you nearly constant time lookup based on a key, but is more complicated than the other options. Problem is that there [is no std library implementation of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c).

Otherwise searching each element is the best you can hope to do with a linked list.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying C11 now implements some.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_%28C%2B%2B%29?

Comment: @user1833028 That is a link to the C++ library version which was indeed introduced this version. I am not aware of C11 that much, so I cant comment about it.