# Structures and dictionary in C

Tags: c

How can I create a dictionary of following type in C ?

```
back={{(0,2,"ADJ"):("NP+V","ADJ",0)},{(0,2,"U"):("NP",".",1)}}
```

I have created a structure as follows:

```
struct bp
{
   char s[20];

   char s1[20];

   int i;

};

struct bp arr[3][3][3];

struct val;

val.s="NP+D";

val.s1="ADJ";

val.i=0;

arr[0][2]["ADJ"]=val;
```

But this method is incorrect because array subscript in arr cannot be a string.

Can someone please give a solution to this problem?

Comment: Dictionary in `c`? O.o

Comment: C does not have a built-in dictionary type. You have to use a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing an array with an integer is a simple mathematical multiplication/addition, which usually corresponds to one or two assembly instructions. Remember, this is what C is good at: very low-level, low-overhead code.  Accessing a collection by some other "object" like a string is not something a computer "knows how to do" natively. It is implemented by the language / runtime / standard library.

A "dictionary", as found in languages and their standard libraries like Java, C#, Python, etc. is often implemented as a [*hashtable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  There is no "standard" implementation for C. You will have to use some other library or, if you're up for a good challenge, write your own.

- [Looking for a good hash table implementation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138742/looking-for-a-good-hash-table-implementation-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

To implement in C a Pythonesque 'dictionary' for:

```
back={{(0,2,"ADJ"):("NP+V","ADJ",0)},{(0,2,"U"):("NP",".",1)}}
```

you are going to need either two structure types (one for the left-hand key, one for the right-hand value), or you'll have use character strings for everything.

Using your code as a loose basis, you might have:

```
struct ap
{
   int i1;
   int i2;
   char s1[20];
};

struct bp
{
   char s1[20];
   char s2[20];
   int i1;
};
```

and maybe:

```
struct Dictionary
{
    struct ap key;
    struct bp value;
};
```

You could then use an initializer:

```
struct Dictionary oed[] =
{
    { { 0, 2, "ADJ" }, { "NP+V", "ADJ", 0 } },
    { { 0, 2, "U"   }, { "NP",   ".",   1 } },
};
```

If you need to create and populate a structure, you can either use a C99 compound literal:

```
struct Dictionary chambers = (struct Dictionary){ { 0, 2, "ADJ" }, { "NP+V", "ADJ", 0 } };
```

or do the assignments piecemeal:

```
struct Dictionary merriam;

merriam.key   = (struct ap){ 0, 2, "ADJ" };
merriam.value = (struct bp){ "NP+V", "ADJ", 0 };
```

or do the assignments a member at a time:

```
struct Dictionary webster;

webster.key.i1 = 0;
webster.key.i2 = 2
strcpy(webster.key.s1, "ADJ");
strcpy(webster.value.s1, "NP+V");
strcpy(webster.value.s2, "ADJ");
webster.value.i1 = 0;
```

Note that this outline simply deals with storing the data.  It does not deal with hashing the key value or other fancy (necessary) memory management.  The code assumes that the strings will fit; it should check that the strings *do* fit.

There is, however, no standard C library for managing such structures; you either have to write your own or borrow someone else's library.