# Creating Hash tables in C

Tags: c, hashtable

I am a newbie to the concept of Hash tables.I am trying to create a very simple hash table to understand the concept. I have understood how to create basic hash function for the purpose of hashing. However I do not understand how to link it to the rest of the table. I am confused on how to begin to create the table , make a look up function, deleting entry in the tables and so on.

The hash function looks somethin like this [found here](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml).

```
unsigned int hash(hash_table_t *hashtable, char *str)
{
    unsigned int hashval;

    /* we start our hash out at 0 */
    hashval = 0;

    /* for each character, we multiply the old hash by 31 and add the current
     * character.  Remember that shifting a number left is equivalent to 
     * multiplying it by 2 raised to the number of places shifted.  So we 
     * are in effect multiplying hashval by 32 and then subtracting hashval.  
     * Why do we do this?  Because shifting and subtraction are much more 
     * efficient operations than multiplication.
     */
    for(; *str != '\0'; str++) hashval = *str + (hashval << 5) - hashval;

    /* we then return the hash value mod the hashtable size so that it will
     * fit into the necessary range
     */
    return hashval % hashtable->size;
}
```

But I do not understand the other parts like how to create the table, look up and so on..

Could somebody please help me. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: The question is too broad to give a good answer, but you might want to look up how singly-linked lists can be implemented. Each bucket in a hash table can be implemented using a singly-linked list, so once you have that working you could test your hash table by using a constant hash function (i.e. which always yields the same hash sum) such that everything ends up in the same bucket.

Comment: You could find some implementations examples in this other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1138742/3545273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic concept is easy:

1. use a very large array to store the data
2. use the hash function to index the array
3. you will have collisions- so figure out a mechanism to deal with those ( a linked list is probably the easiest)

So, when you want to write data : `index =  hash_function(); array[index] = data.` Similar for read.

You will figure the rest out once you read more about hash tables.

Answer (score 1):

**Very** simply put a hash table works by splitting the data up into smaller storage units (called buckets). Those internal storage units are accessed by the index and the index is the hash code of the values stored inside the buckets. Note the s in *values*. You need to be able to store multiple values in one bucket to support hash code collisions.

So there are a couple of basic operations one expects from a hash table.

1. **Contains** - To do a contains check you need to calculate the hash value to find the bucket the data should be in. Once the correct bucket is found you need to check every item in there for equality (how ever you choose to implement this.)
2. **Add** - Adding a new item to the table requires a similar check like in the *Contains* to prevent that you add any item twice.
3. **Remove** - You can guess. Find the item the same way as your *Contains* does and remove it from the buckets.

That being said, you need to implement the buckets. Plainly said you need a list of lists. For the first layer you need some collection that supports indexed access. Since you use C, a simple array is the way to go. I suggest you don't use the full range of the integer for your buckets (you can do, but that will make it harder to understand and debug). Simply apply a modulo operation to reduce the range of your hash code properly. For the second part I suggest something like a chained list to support dynamic growing.

So you find your chained list based on the array index and then you process every item in the chained list to find the correct item. This also shows why hash collisions reduce the efficiency of hash tables. If you have no hash collisions you only need one test to find the item and that is time constant. If you have hash collisions you need to check multiple values.

Hash collisions are two different values returning the same hash code.

Hope that gives you a idea how to start. And don't listen to anyone. C is a awesome language to get started.

Comment: Thank you for that help. It made the concept much clearer :) I will try to implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather tan telling you how to code this, I will tell you the name of the field you are trying to learn: [Data Structures and Algorithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Algorithms%20Data%20Structures)

Most books on this matter, will give you an example on how to create a hash table. My advice, start with an easier language than C, get the concept, and then go back to C.

Comment: Thank you for that reply. I actually have understood the concept of Hash Tables. I  know how it works. All I need is a simple example on how to create the hash table now. But thanks anyway for the help :)

Comment: Most books, have also code examples ...