# Is there a good collection library for C-language?

Tags: c, data-structures, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Container Class / Library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c)

We have to maintain and even develop C-code of our legacy system. Is there good collection library that would support Java/C# (new versions) style collections. Hashtable, HashSet, etc. Of course without objects, but with structs. The HashTable key limitations to "strings" and ints is not a problem. It wouldn't be bad if it's free even for commercial use. I'm back to C from C# and I must say i'm depressed using our own libraries and the language in general. We're using VS2005 and MS C-compiler if that has nothing to do with anything.

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c among others.

Answer (score 7):

I warmly recommend [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/), the general-purpose library that lies underneath the GTK+ widget toolkit. It's excellent.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101119053156/http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~cwc22/hashtable/) is a hashtable in C, and a more general library [here](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The first link is broken. Best to describe what you're linking to in your post, so people can find it later if the link breaks.