# dictionary/map/key-value pairs data structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures

How does one construct and access a set of key-value pairs in C? To use a silly simple example, let's say I want to create a table which translates between an integer and its square root.

If I were writing javascript, I could just do this:

```
var squareRoots = {
   4: 2,
   9: 3,
   16: 4,
   25: 5
}
```

and then access them like:

```
var squareRootOf25 = squareRoots[5]
```

How do I do this in C? What if I want to use one type of enum as the key and another type of enum as the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider hash implementation in C language to achieve this.
For basics of hash refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).
Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c/306461#306461) for more details and links.

This [link](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/summary.html) gives good overview and implementation details.

Comment: Short of writing a domain-specific language to generate C code or a resource file, you cannot reasonably specify a predefined lookup table at compile time, as the question seems to suggest is wanted. Even a sorted array to binary search is prone to ordering errors. +1 anyway, though, because that almost certainly doesn't matter. Just fill your data structure during your apps initialisation from a simple array of items. The run-time cost is rarely if ever an issue. The Javascript example effectively does this anyway, but with language-supplied container-filling code.

Comment: Run-time generation is just fine for my current needs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do this unless you count initializing an array like this in C99:

```
double squareRoots[] =
{
     [4] = 2.0,
     [9] = 3.0,
    [16] = 4.0,
    [25] = 5.0,
};
```

However, this allocates 26 elements in the array; the other values are all zeroes.

Assuming you didn't mean this, then look at [C Interfaces and Implementations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201498413) by D R Hanson; it shows a way of implementing associative arrays (aka hashes or dictionaries).

Comment: Nice lesson in C99, though - I wasn't aware of this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the libghthash for general purpose hashes.  They are quite easy to use, and incorporate in your application.  However, it is a third party API - so if that's  a problem, you would have to implement your own.

There's no built in associate array/hash tables in C.

The array initialization (C99) is probably the best way to go unless you have non-numeric keys:

```
T hash[] = {
    [1] = tObj,
    [255] = tObj2,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be solved using a map. Unfortunately, there is no data structure in C that is quite alike to a map **(A map is a container that stores elements in a key-value pair fashion. Each element has a unique key that is used to access the corresponding value. Maps are typically implemented as balanced binary search trees, which provide efficient lookup and insertion operations)**. That means you should implement it yourself.
Although this might not be the optimal approach to this challenge, I have implemented a map using Binary Search Tree structure, not ensuring the fact that  the worst time complexity is not linear. Another data structure which ensures that the worst time complexity is still O(log2(n)) is the self-balancing Red-Black Tree.
I will next present my attempt in implementing the requested so-called map.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Pair{
    char *first;
    int second;
};
struct Pair *make_pair(char *a,int b){
    struct Pair *x=(struct Pair *)malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
    x->first=strdup(a);
    x->second=b;
    return x;
};
int make_hash(char *s,int size){
    unsigned long long hash=5813;
    for(int i=0;s[i];i++) hash=hash*33+s[i];
    return (hash%size);
}
int compare(char *a,char *b){
    //Hello! I am the compare function and I:
    // return -1, if a and b are the same.
    // return 0, if a "<" b.
    // return 1, if a ">" b.
    int i=0,x=0;
    for(;a[i]&&b[i];i++){
        if(b[i]>a[i]) return 0;
        if(b[i]==a[i])x++;
    }
    if(!a[i]&&!b[i]&&x==i)
    return -1;
    if(!a[i]&&b[i])
    return 0;
    return 1;
};
struct Nod{
    struct Pair *val;
    struct Nod *st,*dr;
};
struct Tree{
    struct Nod *top;
};
void addtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s,int val){
    if(!t->top){
        t->top=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
        t->top->val=make_pair(s,val);
        t->top->st=NULL;
        t->top->dr=NULL;
        return;
    };
    struct Nod *nod=t->top;
    while(nod){
        int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
        if(x==1){
            if(nod->dr){
                nod=nod->dr;
            }
            else{
                nod->dr=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
                nod->dr->val=make_pair(s,val);
                nod->dr->dr=NULL;
                nod->dr->st=NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        if(x==0){
            if(nod->st){
                nod=nod->st;
            }
            else{
                nod->st=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
                nod->st->val=make_pair(s,val);
                nod->st->dr=NULL;
                nod->st->st=NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        if(x==-1){
            nod->val->second=val;
            return;
        }
    }
}
void poptotree(struct Tree *t,char *s){
    if(!t->top) return;
    int u=0;
    struct Nod *nod=t->top,*p=NULL,*te=NULL;
    while(nod){
        te=nod;
        int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
        if(x==1) nod=nod->dr,u=1;
        if(x==0) nod=nod->st,u=0;
        if(x==-1){
            if(nod->st&&nod->dr){
                struct Nod *search=nod->st,*pa=NULL;
                while(search->dr) pa=search,search=search->dr;
                if(pa){
                    pa->st=search->st;
                    pa->dr=NULL;
                    nod->val=make_pair(search->val->first,search->val->second);
                    free(search->val);
                    free(search);
                }
                else{
                    nod->st=nod->st->st;
                    nod->val=make_pair(search->val->first,search->val->second);
                    free(search->val);
                    free(search);
                }
                return;
            }
            else if(!nod->st&&nod->dr){
                if(p){
                    if(u){
                        p->dr=nod->dr;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                    else{
                        p->st=nod->dr;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    t->top=nod->dr;
                    free(nod->val);
                    free(nod);
                }
                return;
            }
            else if(nod->st&&!nod->dr){
                if(p){
                    if(u){
                        p->dr=nod->st;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                    else{
                        p->st=nod->st;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    t->top=nod->st;
                    free(nod->val);
                    free(nod);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(p){
                    if(u){
                        p->dr=NULL;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                    else{
                        p->st=NULL;
                        free(nod->val);
                        free(nod);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    free(t->top->val);
                    free(t->top);
                    t->top=NULL;
                }
            }
            return;
            }
        p=te;
    }
}
struct Nod *findtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s){
    struct Nod *nod=t->top;
    while(nod){
        int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
        if(x==1)nod=nod->dr;
        if(x==0)nod=nod->st;
        if(x==-1){
            return nod;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
struct Map{
    struct Tree **t;
    int size;
};
struct Map *createMap(int size){
    if(size<=0) return NULL;
    struct Map *m=(struct Map *)malloc(sizeof(struct Map));
    m->size=size;
    m->t=(struct Tree **)calloc(size,sizeof(struct Tree *));
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) m->t[i]=NULL;
    return m;
};
void add(struct Map *m,char *s,int val){
    int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
    if(!m->t[hash]){
        m->t[hash]=(struct Tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
        m->t[hash]->top=NULL;
    };
    addtotree(m->t[hash],s,val);
};
void pop(struct Map *m,char *s){
    int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
    if(!m->t[hash]) return;
    poptotree(m->t[hash],s);
};
int find(struct Map *m,char *s){
    int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
    if(!m->t[hash]) return 0;
    struct Nod *nod=findtotree(m->t[hash],s);
    if(nod) return nod->val->second;
    return 0;
};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](http://code.google.com/p/cstl/source/browse/src/c_map.c) implemented as part of [clib](http://code.google.com/p/cstl/) library