# Data structure to hold string transformations

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a set of rules for string transformation that I parse from a file.  The rules look like this:

```
'aaa' -> 'bbb'

'aa' -> 'bc'
```

Assuming I know how to parse the file, what would be a good data structure in C to hold these transformations? Later on I will need to go through the data structure and get both the 'input' and the 'output' of the transformation for **all** the rules.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need a hash.

Comment: there is a similar answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551677/dictionary-map-key-value-pairs-data-structure-in-c

Comment: Why would a hash be good here? Wouldn't a linked list of structs that contain 'input' and 'output' be enough?

Comment: @HommerSmith: yes, but thats much less efficient.

Comment: Linuxios. Why is less efficient? I won't need to go to a particular 'input'. I need to iterate over all of them.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Than you've answered your own question.

Comment: @HommerSmith To extend Linuxios' answer: Using a hashtable you can calculate the position in the table of translation rules which reduces the effort to find the rule to lookup in the table + calculating the hash. Iterating through the linked list will neither be a constant effort nor faster than a simple lookup.

Comment: I don't need to find any rule. I need to iterate over all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct map {
  char* key;
  char* value;
};
```

Assuming you know all the key's you can then make an array of these structs, traverse it searching by key, then use the associated value.

Comment: Note you can also search for keys by value similarly.