# Is there any standardized and commonly-used library for C (C99 or whatever), as STL is for C++?

Tags: c++, c, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Container Class / Library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c)

I expect I'd be forced to use vectors, lists and sets for my C program. Should I invent those entities from scratch, or there is some kind of standard library for C as STL is for C++ ?

Comment: duplicated question see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c

Comment: take a look at GLib: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html

Comment: If you want to use abstract vectors, lists, and sets then you should probably be writing C++, not C. Copying the idioms of a higher-level language onto C will defeat any advantage C has and will result in much uglier code than if you just wrote it in the higher-level language to begin with. See any `glib`/`gtk` code for a great example of this.

Comment: @Christoph: Haha your comment showed up just as soon as I added mine citing glib as why this is a bad idea. :-)

Comment: @R..: I've never used it extensively, but as far as I can tell, GLib is decent enough - it's GObject which tries to push square blocks through round holes; there's a reason why the GNOME guys created Vala as a frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [APR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Portable_Runtime), or [GLib](http://www.gtk.org/). Those are widely used portable C libraries with everything you need not to reinvent the wheel each time.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have templates, so it might be difficult to implement those C++ collections in a generic way.   I'm not aware of any libraries that implement those features in C.

If I were faced with such a situation, my first thought would be to isolate the parts
of my program that would benefit from C++ features, write them in C++, then provide
an `extern "C"` interface to those modules so they could be called from the pure C
parts of the program.  Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [standard c library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), but it does not have any support for built-in container types such as the ones you list.

Comment: Yes, but C99 has some built-in features in their new array type, no?