# What is a pure-C alternative to STL containers?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stl, ansi-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Container Class / Library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c)

One of the primary reasons to use C++ over C is the superbly convenient containers that STL provides. However, if I want to write my code in pure C and not have to write all my containers from scratch, what alternative do I have ?

Some of the ones that I have heard of (but never used) are

- Glib
- iMatix Standard Function Library
- disparate elements from the Linux kernel headers (e.g. [list](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/))

Any opinions and/or experiences with containers in pure C (Ansi or otherwise) would be much appreciated.

Comment: The real question is, why do you want to write in C? It is really not possible to produce robust container libraries in C, and C++ compilers are available for all but the smallest of platforms, so why not use C++?

Comment: thank you for the trolls. But I should take some of the blame myself - I should have simply asked about containers in C and left it at that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend GLib solely because it's got a nice set of features and it's relatively mature, stable, portable, and widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You, or a library writer, can write containers etc. each time you want to use them for a different type, possibly putting definitions into gigantic macros, or you can use `void *` for containers, losing all hope of type safety and sometimes some performance.  (C's `qsort` function can be significantly less efficient than C++'s `sort` template.)  There is no way to get the equivalent of C++ containers, iterators, and algorithms in C.

I don't know much about Glib, and your reference to disparate elements from Linux kernel headers is a little vague.  The Linux list you mention is probably typical of what you'd get:  no type safety and a set of well-written functions that will be named differently for each data type.  A quick look at iMatix didn't disclose any containers.

Comment: What are you talking about? if you don't know Glib why do you answer? C++ compiler is written in C and you claim "There is no way to have C++ containers and etc in C?  the only difference is syntax otherwise you can have everything in C, the Entire Unix OSes, BSD, Linux and etc are written in C

Comment: @kay:  The question of what you can write in C is irrelevant to the question of what language constructs you can build in C.  If you mean that you can write a compiler for another language in C, and use that instead, you're missing the point.