# What is the best way to manage a queue of structs in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, queue

I've got a series of structs (audio data) which I need to hold onto but I can only hold onto a limited amount due to memory constraints. I think the best way to do this is with a queue. If I were do this based on my fuzzy memories of my college classes I would create a linked list with pointers. I would push new items onto the queue and pop old items off and free that memory.

Is there a C library that I use should to manage this queue so that I do not have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c

Comment: I question the use of a queue for this.  What if your queue holds three items?  You load sound A, B, and C.  Now you use A three more times.  A is most frequently used, and most recently used.  But now you load sound D.  This would push A out of the queue.  Is that the behavior you want?  (Or am I not understanding the question?)

Comment: @Marvo: linked lists are okay if your substitution policy is a FIFO/LIFO one.

Comment: This is a FIFO queue. I will fill it up with the first set of audio samples and as it needs more audio as it plays the audio I will remove the audio which has passed and add more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) has a good and well-documented collection of data structures implemented in C, give a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++, you have std::list in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're describing is a `cache`, not a `queue`.